# Vue.JS 3 testing with JEST and Vuetify 3

Tags: jestjs, vuejs3, vuetify.js

have an issue by testing vue3 components using vuetify components with JEST.

Vuetify component are not rendered so all nested component are also not rendered in unit TEST.

When, i log the `wrapper.html()`, i got vuetify component not rendered like :

`"vform" instead of "[...]form[...]"`

with this configuration:

```
const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives
  });
  let wrapper: VueWrapper;
  let component: any;
  let onSubmitMock: jest.Mock;
  function init(props: {
    [...]
  } = {}) {
    wrapper = shallowMount(ContextForm, {
      props: {
        ...props
      },
      global: {
        plugins: [
          vuetify
        ],
        mocks: {
          $t: jest.fn((key: string) => `{{${key}}}`)
        }
      }
    });
    component = wrapper.vm;
  }
```

its appear the form.validate() is not a function in my tests.

```
const form = this.$refs.form as VForm;
      if (!form.validate()) {
```